Can I travel while waiting for my student visa card?
I am currently studying in Sweden as a non-EU citizen.I got my fingerprints and picture taken for my student residence Visa card but didn’t get it in the mail on time for my trip to Hungary. I’m past the 90th day by 2 days by the time I go back to Sweden.  I know they check your passport at the Copenhagen airport when leaving it. Am I going to get in trouble?

For clarity, how long have you been in Hungary? Is this a first-time residence application or a renewal? AFAIK for first-time applications usually it is not allowed to travel until the decision on your residence status has been made, even within Schengen area or your home country.
